# Simple generalization to Heron's algorithm for finding kth roots

Tags: numerical-methods

There is a simple generalization to Heron's algorithm for finding $k$th roots as follows: $$x←1/k·((k-1)x+y/x^{k-1})$$ Show that, if this converges, it converges to a solution of $x^k=y$. Examine the speed of convergence both computationally and by estimating the error algebraically.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know Newton's method and its convergence behavior? Then try it for $f(x)=x^k-y$.

Then use
$$
f(x_+)=\frac{f''(\tilde x)f(x)^2}{2f'(x)^2}
$$
and that close to the root $x^*$ one has, to first order, $f(x)=f'(x^*)(x-x^*)$ so that the function value is proportional to the distance to the root.

Or use a more direct means of computing the difference progression starting with
$$
x_+-\sqrt[k]y=\frac1k\left((k-1)(x-\sqrt[k]y)+\sqrt[k]y\frac{\sqrt[k]y^{k-1}-x^{k-1}}{x^{k-1}}\right)=…
$$